# Check if Rectangle is between two points

Tags: java, point

If I have point A, point B and point C.  In Java, how would I check if any of the rectangle is in-between the two points?

Comment: Any two points? Or specifically one pair?

Comment: Think of it in math terms before trying to write code.  How would you solve this mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `intersectsLine(Line2D l)` method of `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D`:

```
Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(double x, double y, double w, double h);
System.out.println(rect.intersectsLine(new Line2D.Double(double xA, double yA, double xB, double yB)));
```

where xA,yA, xB,yB are the x and y coordinates, respectively, of points A and B which you wish to check if the rectangle is between.